# How many combinations and permutations can we write number as a sum?

Tags: summation, permutations, combinations

I would like to count number of combinations and permutations we can write number $N$ as a sum of positive numbers.

For example:

Combinations$(3)=3$ ; $(1+1+1, 1+2, 2+1)$

Permutations$(3)=2$ ; $(1+1+1, 1+2)$

Combinations$(4)=7$ ; $(1+1+1+1, 1+1+2, 1+2+1, 2+1+1, 1+3, 3+1, 2+2)$

Permutations$(4)=4$ ; $(1+1+1+1, 1+1+2, 1+3, 2+2)$

What is the formula to calculate number of such combinations and permutations for $N$?

Comment: This is discussed in some detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)). What you call "combinations" are in fact compositions of $n$, while the other is partitions of $n$.

Comment: Compositions are described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)). The number of compositions is just $2^{n-1}$, but the number of partitions is perhaps best calculated by a recursive formula. The Wikipedia pages discusss these things at length. Did they answer the question?

Comment: By the way, for things that we call combinations and permutations, usually the permutations are the ones where we count different-ordered lists as distinct things, and combinations are the ones where we count only one of the orderings. That is, each combination may be counted as several permutations. There are then more permutations than combinations.